# Weird things happened between printing log and not printing log

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm facing a weird problem when running my application.
I have a code to break paragraph into lines. When run it without printing log below each row of code, my code run totally wrong. It breaks line when has not reached width of row yet, creating paragraph like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
```

But when I insert log to print result of each line of code, my code runs nearly perfectly like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
```

My logs are just for printing value in each variables, they do not calculate anything.

**My question is:** have you guys ever got somethings like this, different results between printing log and not printing log when running application? Why it happens? How to solve it?

Thank you.

### Update

Below is my code which split paragraph into rows. With `boolean log = false`, it will return wrong result.

```
public static ArrayList<Row> getRows(int displayWidth, String text, TextStyle style) {
    // Split to words
    ArrayList<String> punctuations = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    
    boolean log = true;
    text = text.replace("\\r\\n", "");

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    int lastCutIndex = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        words.add(text.substring(lastCutIndex, m.start()));

        if (m.end() <= text.length()) {
            punctuations.add(text.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
        }

        lastCutIndex = m.end();
    }

    if (lastCutIndex < text.length()) words.add(text.substring(lastCutIndex, text.length()));
    
    // Fill words into row
    int full = getSize("a b", style)[0];
    int less = getSize("ab", style)[0];
    int spaceCharWidth = full - less;

    int currentRow = 0;

    rows.add(new Row(style.getTypeface(), style.getTextSize()));

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        int[] rowSize = getSize(rows.get(currentRow).getText(), style); 
        int rowWidth = rowSize[0];
        int rowHeight = rowSize[1];

        rows.get(currentRow).lineHeight = 
                FastMath.round(rowHeight * style.line_mult + style.line_add);

        String word = words.get(i);
        String punc = "";
        if (i < punctuations.size()) punc = punctuations.get(i);
        
        if (log) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "word:" + word + ",punc:" + punc + "|");
        }

        int puncWidth = 0;
        if (punc.equals(" ")) puncWidth = spaceCharWidth;
        else puncWidth = getSize(punc, style)[0];

        int nextWordWidth = getSize(word, style)[0];
        
        if (log) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "nexWordWidth:" + nextWordWidth);
        }

        int predictWidth = FastMath.round(rowWidth + nextWordWidth 
                + (rows.get(currentRow).elementCount - 1) * WIDTH_ADD_RATIO);

        if (log) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "predictWidth:" + predictWidth);
        }

        if (punc.equals(" ")) {
            if (log) {
                Logger.e(TAG, "predict is < displayWidth?" + ((predictWidth < displayWidth) ? true : false));
            }

            if (predictWidth < displayWidth) {
                rows.get(currentRow).append(word);

                if (predictWidth + puncWidth < displayWidth) {
                    rows.get(currentRow).append(punc);
                }

                if (log) {
                    Logger.e(TAG, "rows[" + currentRow + "]:" + rows.get(currentRow).getText());
                }

            } else {
                currentRow++;

                if (log) {
                    Logger.e(TAG, "new row");
                }

                Row row = new Row(style.getTypeface(), style.getTextSize());
                row.append(word);

                if (word.equals("")) {
                    if (!punc.equals(" ")) {
                        row.append(punc);
                    }
                } else {
                    row.append(punc);
                }

                rows.add(row);

                if (log) {
                    Logger.e(TAG, "rows[" + currentRow + "]:" + rows.get(currentRow).getText());
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (log) {
                Logger.e(TAG, "predict + puncWidth is < displayWidth?" + ((predictWidth < displayWidth) ? true : false));
            }

            if (predictWidth + puncWidth < displayWidth) {
                rows.get(currentRow).append(word);
                rows.get(currentRow).append(punc);

                if (log) {
                    Logger.e(TAG, "rows[" + currentRow + "]:" + rows.get(currentRow).getText());
                }

            } else {
                currentRow++;
                if (log) {
                    Logger.e(TAG, "new row");
                }

                Row row = new Row(style.getTypeface(), style.getTextSize());
                row.append(word);

                if (word.equals("")) {
                    if (!punc.equals(" ")) {
                        row.append(punc);
                    }
                } else {
                    row.append(punc);
                }

                rows.add(row);
                if (log) {
                    Logger.e(TAG, "rows[" + currentRow + "]:" + rows.get(currentRow).getText());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return rows;
}

public static int[] getSize(String text, TextStyle style) {
    if (text == null) return new int[2];

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(style.getTextSize());
    paint.setTypeface(style.getTypeface());
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text.toCharArray(), 0, text.length(), rect);
    
    int[] result = new int[2];
    result[0] = rect.width();
    result[1] = rect.height();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: suspect your code.....narrow down to a small portion of code that exhibits behaviour and post here....

Comment: i agree with @MitchWheat i would think this is a problem in your code.

Comment: @MitchWheat & Sean F: I updated my code.

Comment: we really don't want to check all your code!....

Comment: Well I though so before posted the question so I didnt include it in first place, but sometimes I get this problem, not just when splitting paragraph like this, but when calculate this or that, it happens and i have no clue why! So i think i may ask, maybe someone will have an answer. Thank you anyway.